# how to find out which of my chrome plugins(extensions) changes my site

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Recently I just found sometimes when I use https://www.baidu.com/ 
it's turn to be www.baidu.com/?tn=92276401_hao_pg. 
It's an id that Identify something and I want to find out which my chrome plugin did this. I was thinking a way but just can't figure out how to located this problem.so could someone give me some inspiration or procedures to help me how to locate which of my plugin doing this to me? 
(both of chrome in my win and mac face the same problem,so I think it's about the plugin,If I may thinking wrong plz correct me )

Comment: I guess one of my plugin set a hook or filter,just can't located it?Is there someone knows some tool could help me? T_T

Answer (score 0):

From https://chineseseoshifu.com/blog/complete-list-of-baidu-search-url-parameters.html :

tn is a referral tag. “baiduhome_pg” means Baidu homepage; “sitehao123” means the referrer is hao123.com.

This is most likely something originating from the site you clicked the Baidu link on, and has nothing to do with your browser or plugins.

Comment: each time I just clicked sited in my bookmark and I'm sure it's correct.and it's not always change,just sometimes,so made me fell just couldn't located this problem.

Comment: From what I read, it could also be caused by the Baidu searchbar, if you're using one.

Comment: didn't install it :( I have some extensions